# How to come back from iframe to main page to work on main page elements - using selenium webdriver

Tags: iframe, selenium, webdriver

I have used `Driver.switchTo().frame("XXXXX");`  to go to iframe on the main page

Now I want to go back to Main page to work with other operation using selenium webdriver

I had tried to get window handles

but I can't get iFrame window handle

Comment: @Jasmine.Olivra: How did you resolve that? what's the way? It's better to mention here

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: This is perfect solution. Please add me in your personal Email Chat My email ID is Jasmine.Olivra@gmail.com

Comment: This is actually kind of dangerous to do. Sometimes, when you call the driver.switchTo().defaultContent() twice, you'll actually get a different result.  The Java Doc states: Selects either the first frame on the page, or the main document when a page contains iframes. So if you are already in the root frame you end up in the first frame with all the chaos this brings. So always test if you are already in the root frame (javascript -> return self.location === top.location;) Credit to @Martin Kersten

Comment: I don't know why, but this isn't working for me